# Will built-in `operator->` be used if I don't overload it?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The builtin `operator->` is defined as `(*p).m`, which is just fine for my iterator, so overloading it would just waste my time and the maintainer's eyes.

Just trying it wouldn't guarantee portability, and I haven't been able to find an answer, though I fear that it is no, because apparently nobody has even considered it before.

Update:
I made a minimal test program to actually try this:

```
struct S { int m;};

struct P
{   auto& operator*() const { return s;}
    auto operator->() const =default;// { return &s;}
    S s;
};

int main()
{   P p;
    p->m;
}
```

g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) compiles this only without `=default;//`, so seems like defaulting or omitting the overload won't be portable for years at least.

Comment: Built-in `operator->` exists only for pointer types. Class types must overload it explicitly.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I wish I could at least default it to the desired effect.

Comment: That would be nice, but I think it wouldn't be possible with the way `operator->` is defiined (it will be called recursively for as long as `operator->` exists for the return type). It would require direct compiler support to enable such trick.

Comment: I don't see why `= default` is better than `{ return /*some ptr*/; } `, or `{ return &**this; }` if it's code reuse that bothers you.

Comment: *"Just trying it wouldn't guarantee portability,"* -- true, so this would be a negative test, rather than a positive one. If you try it and it works, you conclude nothing. However, if you try it and it does not work, then you can conclude that it is not a portable solution.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It's harder to get wrong and faster read.

Comment: @JaMiT It still leaves the possibility that something I haven't tried would work, though I can't imagine what could work beside defaulting.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see your working implementation as a [mcve], even if it does not guarantee portability.  Also share what operating system you are using, compiler, compiler version, and how you are building.

Comment: *"compiles this only with the commented out definition"* So you mean "compiles only if you uncomment the definition"? The wording confused me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's right. It compiles only without "=default;//". I wished that the compiler would just use operator* if I don't provide operator->. I asked this question to get it settled in my mind.

Comment: @learnedSloth If you want your `operator->` to just use `opeartor*` then you can use `operator*` from inside `operator->`. Something like: `auto operator->() { return &this->operator*();}`. See [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/o9LlaFEik)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will built-in `operator->` be used if I don't overload it?

No, only certain **special member functions** are implicitly declared for a given *class-type*(and that too under certain circumstances). And `operator->` is not one of them. This can be seen from [special members](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/) which states:

> The **six special members functions described above are members implicitly declared** on classes under certain circumstances:
>
> - Default ctor
> - Dtor
> - Copy ctor
> - Copy assignment
> - Move ctor
> - Move assignment

(emphasis mine)

Note in the above list, there is no mention of `operator->`. This means that if you want to use `->` with an object of your *class-type* then you must overload it explicitly.

---

Now, coming to your question about the error that you're getting.

> compiles this only with the commented out definition, so seems like defaulting or omitting the overload won't be portable for years at least.

You're getting the error because `operator->` **cannot be defaulted**. This can be seen from the same [special members documentation](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/) which says:

> each class can select explicitly **which of these members** exist with their default definition or which are deleted by using the keywords `default` and `delete`, respectively.

(emphasis mine)

Note the emphasis on "these members" above. In particular, only the six special members listed above can be defaulted. And again since `operator->` is not one of them, it can't be defaulted using `default`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Anoop Rana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72683207/19366831) pointed out, only special member functions can be defaulted, and, as [Yksisarvinen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72673535/will-built-in-operator-be-used-if-i-dont-overload-it?noredirect=1#comment128369739_72673535) said, the builtin operator-> exists only for builtin types.

Redundancy in overloaded operators is a long acknowledged problem.
[Boost::Operators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/utility/doc/html/utility/utilities/operators.html) provides common overloads with CRTP,
including operator-> that mimics the builtin behavior:

```
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

struct S { int m;};

struct P : boost::dereferenceable< P, const S*>
{   auto& operator*() const { return s;}
    S s;
};

int main()
{   P p;
    p->m;
}
```

Unfortunately spelling out the return type is required.
(It shouldn't be required IMHO.)
Alone it isn't a big step forward, but
it's bundled in commonly needed groups like `input_iteratable`.